# Is there any way to get more details of a ansible task

Tags: ansible

```
ansible-playbook —list-tasks —tag<tagname>
```

Lists the tasknames. Is there way to get more details of task other than name?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the end result of each task without executing the tasks,

Ansible provides a check mode, also called dry run mode that predicts the changes that may occur in each task without actually executing it.

```
ansible-playbook --check your_playbook.yaml
```